# Implementing file upload functionality that support Android devices in a web view via React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a page:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
//import react in our code.
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, WebView } from 'react-native';
//import all the basic component we have used

export default class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  //Profile Screen to show from Open profile button
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'mobilesite'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

On this mobile site, I have a `<input type="file" />` element; in testing, I noticed that the file upload functionality works in iOS devices but not Android.

I've researched various threads on this topic, but many are from 1 year or older. I'd like to doublecheck with the developer community that a better solution (that I haven't yet researched) is available?

Comment: https://github.com/andreipfeiffer/react-native-webview-android-file-upload ..... try this package insted

Comment: Thank you! The package you referenced has been deprecated as the functionality is now available in this package: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview (I just tested and it works in Android and iOS!), also to anyone reading this who's just getting into app development and who may be frustrated when they hit a roadblock, please keep learning, you'll get there, one step at a time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Akshay Mulgavkar for the initial suggestion! https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview (I just tested and it works in Android and iOS!), also to anyone reading this who's just getting into app development and who may be frustrated when they hit a roadblock, please keep learning, you'll get there, one step at a time :)